# How to regain control of your system when it runs out of memory?

Tags: 18.04, ram, system

Suppose your system only has 4GB of memory (not much in 2019), and you are running Ubuntu 18.04 (64 bit). You have a couple of tabs open in Firefox, a few tabs in a terminal are running some scripts, and then you "carelessly" decide to start a video editor, do a few edits and *bang!*, you suddenly run out of memory. Your system becomes totally unresponsive, you can't move the mouse or launch a terminal window to kill something to free up memory, and `Ctrl+Alt+Del` doesn't do anything either. Your system's only sign of life is the noise the disk makes while being busy trying to swap things without end.

What can you do in this situation, other than tapping your power switch? I read somewhere that when you run out of memory, Linux will start killing processes at random, but I've never experienced that ever happen.

Comment: If there is swap space still available, the kernel won't start killing things. If you want to avoid the disk I/O hit causing this issue, you can buy more RAM (assuming the hardware is capable enough to add it) and disable swap, so that you won't hit the disk. Another option is to enable zRAM, which compresses a porition of memory to give you "more" at the cost of increased latency due to the compression/decompression, when hitting that section of memory. And further, you can switch to a lighter environment, such as xfce to save some memory.

Comment: Is there anyone to get a warning before memory and swap run full, so that the user can manually kill a few programs to avoid this. It's really really annoying.

Comment: A workaround I've found is tab suspending extensions for browsers like Firefox, Chromium. These allow to toss of some memory load, but they don't solve the problem ultimately.